# Java swing window gets corrupted when resized

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, gridbaglayout

I am having this issue with the JDialog, that gets corrupted when resized or when in general is smaller than a certain size.
To develop, all components are placed using GridBagLayout.

Here is an example:
A good version:
[image]

However, when user is using a laptop with the smaller screen, they can't see this dialog complete.  But, when resize is attempted, the components get corrupted when the dialog window is smaller than a certain size.
[image]

Can anyone help with understanding what Layout is better to use, so that the components in all entirety would be preserved ?

I tried using these flags, and to no avail:

```
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Comment: Yes, GBL will tend to squash components down when the GUI has less space than can accommodate the displaying component at the preferred size. A call to [`Window.setMinimumSize(Dimension)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize(java.awt.Dimension)) after `pack()` might help. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: That's a pretty big panel, so you could put the entire thing in a scroll pane.

Comment: GridBagLayout will shrink components to their minimum size when space is not available to show the component at its preferred size. Since you appear to have plenty of space, the problem is with your usage of the GridBagLayout. You need to rethink your layout. Maybe use nested panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.